# New Logo Has a Distracting "Hole"... Why?

Tags: discussion, design, logo

First of all, my apologies for what might seem to some a superfluous question.

The new Stack Overflow logo has a tiny "missing hole" on the letter "a"; see magnified screenshot where I have highlighted it by filling it in red:

[image]

<strike>It is most likely a deliberate visual design feature. However, this sharp, white square is quite distracting: at first I thought my monitor had a dead pixel or something (at least that is the impression it gives on so called "retina" monitors).</strike> *Turns out it is a bug in Safari's rendering of SVG?*

**Does anybody (perhaps someone from the team involved in the design) know the rationale behind it?**

---

Interestingly enough, the logo on the meta version of the site (i.e., on *this* site) does not show the feature. Perhaps the meta site is still using the previous logo?

---

**EDIT:** Well, this is weird: right after capturing the logo, making the screenshot above and posting the question, the logo on the website seems to no longer have the feature...? Then I open a new window, and there it is...

---

**EDIT 2:** Here is a screenshot I just took at 14:30 JST (+0900) where the hole is visible:

[image]

---

**EDIT 3:** The hole seems to appear on Safari (v9.0.3), but not on Firefox (38.6.1) on Mac OS X.

Comment: Zoomed in as much as I could in three browsers and could not replicate this. Are you sure that your (probably) cached image isn't mangled? Otherwise this seems like a rendering error. The logo doesn't have this "hole" (it's an [SVG](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=a7723f5f7e59)).

Comment: Perhaps some CSS bug is causing a tiny white square to appear at that position most of the time? The way the website is coded does not allow to "drag and save" the original image, so I can not test this...

Comment: Thank you for the information about the logo being an SVG. I guess it is a rendering error in Safari's part.

Comment: it's a bug, not a feature ;)

Comment: While not extremely fancy, it is not "obviously ugly" either, so I assumed... ;)

Comment: I can reproduce in Safari 9.0.3, but it disappears as soon as I zoom in.

Comment: I didn't try zooming. My first screenshot is "zoomed" in an image editor (Pixelmator), not live on the browser.

Comment: The Meta version seems to be unaffected.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my original question. I first assumed it was due to the meta site using an older logo (on close inspection, I don't think that's the case).

Comment: Somehow, the particular SVG that results for the meta logo does not trigger the Safari bug...?

Comment: Definitely duplicate of the other linked question. I did search, but evidently missed it. Sorry!

Comment: @NicolasMiari Happens to all. Next time, just look at the list of related questions while typing out your question. You might find a dupe :-)

Comment: I did that too. Guess I didn't hit the right search keywords. :|

Comment: It is Apple's commemorative for the celebrated Steve Jobs, the previous a-hole.

Comment: @HansPassant all the upvotes, to you.